# large app activity dataset and needs to delete the data and at same time insert rows in azure db

Tags: sql, azure

I have a huge dataset with 1000s of rows getting inserted every second as it is a click stream data. DUe to huge size of overall db, my apps response time has increased drastically so i want to delete the data but it is taking huge time because large amount of data is getting inserted at the same time. How can i maintain this click stream data? I have my entire application hosted on Azure using Azure Db.

Thanks

Comment: Partitions maybe?

Comment: This question, as written, is too broad and unanswerable. We know nothing of the types of inserts (and deletes) you're doing (no info on schema at all); no idea if you're topping out the DTU of your database (I'm assuming you're using SQL Database service, though you called it "Azure Db"; no idea if your app is pushing the limit of its capacity (cpu or network). We don't even know how you're hosting your app (web app? vm?) which could directly impact its scale.

Answer (score -1):

Decouple your app woth direct access to your database.
Consider using message borker/queue event hubs in azure. This will allow asynchronous communication between your app and backend. Event hivs are capable of manging backups as well. Then parsed into sql db or persisted into blobs might consider a streaming analytics job whicb may perform an acticity of aggregation

You might have to get your dtus of azure db increased ao that the service broker gets freed up by queued up requests. Check for any constraints being defined which are performing an expensive lookup to further degrade your performance.

Constr

Comment: You're proposing architectural changes to an undefined problem. Message queues, event hubs, brokers, blobs, analytics??? All proposals for re-engineering, when you don't know any specifics of the issue.

Comment: When the design  has issues what do you propose. Why app is getting locked real time click through events never to hook up directly with backend and wait for response. stream analytics job not analytics per se.

Comment: What design issues? We literally have no design details.